# What 変なのあった refers to here?

Tags: meaning

I am uncertain what 変なのあった refers to in the last sentence.

[image]

I think it refers to different computer models. Perhaps, a person who brought these computers?

Comment: This grammatical structure is used through out the paragraph.  How do you understand the other instances?  This instance that you point to is much the same.

Comment: If it referred to a person, the verb would be いる.

Answer (score 1):

変なのあった just means "there were strange ones", where "ones" refer to minor computers other than 9801 series. 変な is "strange", の is "one/thing" (noun), and あった is the existence verb used with an inanimate thing.